# Using BreezeJS with ASP.NET Identity Many-to-Many UserRoles Table

Tags: angularjs, entity-framework, breeze, asp.net-identity

I'm trying to implement `ASP.NET Identity` using `Entity Framework`, `BreezeJS` and `AngularJS`. The approach I'm using for ASP.NET Identity is [here](https://github.com/KriaSoft/AspNet.Identity). One-to-many relationships, such as `Users`-`UserLogins` and `Users`-`UserClaims` work fine; Breeze returns them in a single call, without issue. The problem lies in the fact that the `UserRoles` table in SQL exists with a join table (`UserUserRoles`), which is a many-to-many relationship in EntityFramework that Breeze does not currently support.

The EF designer automatically joins the `User` and `UserRoles` tables with an association 'bridge', which is actually the 'UserUserRoles' table without a visible table, just the connector/association line. I've tried to rearrange the model to create two 1-to-many relationships between `Users` and `UserUserRoles` and `UserRoles` and `UserUserRoles`, thinking Breeze would accept them. But, so far it hasn't worked (it has wreaked havoc on my LINQ-based `WebApi` Controller, the errors of which I have yet to overcome).

I've reviewed the following **[link/Plunkr](http://www.breezejs.com/documentation/presenting-many-many)** as a means of using a `map` on the client for m2m relationships. It looks promising, but I'm trying to understand how to query the ASP.NET Identity EF data model to implement this approach. Or, perhaps that method is not suited for ASP.NET Identity. To that end, **can someone please explain what the EF model and Breeze EntityManager calls must look like to achieve a working (even pseudo-working) relationship for ASP.NET Identity, specifically the** `UserRoles` **relationship**?

BTW, I'm not fully-committed to the EF data model and SQL table configuration in the first link. It's just what I found that initially made sense. If there is a better approach that foregoes the m2m relationship between Users and UserRoles, I'm all for it. However, the underlying problem of not being to query m2m data in Breeze still exists.

**SEE POSSIBLE SOLUTION BELOW...**

Answer (score 0):

**I discovered that, by adding a 3rd column to the** `UserUserRoles` **join table, such as an auto-incrementing identity (int) column - a table which originally had 2 columns that were both foreign keys,** `EntityFramework` **no longer saw the join as a many-to-many relationship, but rather two 1-to-many relationships**. In this way, my Breeze query, which was previously pulling a null result for `UserRoles`, now contains `UserUserRoles` (join table data) field, which subsequently contains the related `UserRoles` data. So, the problem of getting Breeze to query ASP.NET Identity roles has a possible solution. I don't know if this is the best way of doing things, but it seems fairly sound to me. Only further testing will prove that correct or not.

Here is the code I ended up with:

```
var serviceAddress = "../../breeze/identity",
    em = new breeze.EntityManager({
    serviceName: serviceAddress,
});

// Supply username and password as predicates for authentication
var userPredicate = breeze.Predicate.create('userName', 'eq', username);
var passwordPredicate = breeze.Predicate.create('passwordHash', 'eq', password);

var query = new breeze.EntityQuery('Users')
            .where(userPredicate.and(passwordPredicate));

var promise = em.executeQuery(query)
            .catch(queryFailed);

promise.then(function(result) {
        console.log('breeze authentication result', result);

        //jQuery iteration to test results
        var activeRoles = [];
        $.each(result.results[0].userUserRoles, function(i, val){
            activeRoles.push(userRole.userRole.name);
        });
        console.log('active roles', activeRoles);
        //result => ['Administrator', 'Executive']
})
.catch(function(error) {
        console.log('breeze authentication error', error);
 });

function queryFailed(error) {
        return q.reject(error); // so downstream promise users know it failed
}
```

Behind the scenes in my Breeze WebApi Controller, the key was to query the related `UserRoles` data like so:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<User> Users()
{
    var users = _contextProvider.Context.Users
        .Include(u => u.UserLogins)
        .Include(u => u.UserUserRoles.Select(r => r.UserRole))
        .Include(u => u.UserClaims);

    return users;
 }
```

**I'm still wondering if there is a more standardized way of using Breeze with ASP.NET Identity, and more poignantly, with** `EntityFramework` **many-to-many relationships**. If anyone has any suggestions, please post answers/comments to help everyone experiencing this issue.